# Jquery ajax function not working while submitting form

Tags: php, jquery, mysql, ajax

I'm trying to submit a form using ajax and php but for some reason my ajax is not working, when I try to hi the submit button it takes me to the page where my form will be process.

Form

```
<form id='formData' action="process/profile-settings" method="POST">
     <div class="col-md-8">
                 <div class="form-group">
                      <label>Name</label>
                      <input type="text" name="name" class="form-control" value="<?php echo $user->userName(); ?>" disabled />
            </div>
                 <div class="form-group">
                  <label>Description/Bio</label>
                  <input type="text" name="bio" class="form-control" value="" />
                 </div>
     </div>
<button type="submit" class="btn d-block mx-auto" id="save" name="save">Save</button>
</form>
```

Ajax Code

```
$('document').ready(function(e) {
  console.log('readyyyy');
  $("#save").on('submit', function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    console.log('donwwwww');
    var data = $("#formData").serialize();
    $.ajax({
      async: true,
      url: 'process/profile-settings.php',
      data: data,
      cache: false,
      contentType: false,
      processData: false,
      type: 'post',
      success: (response) => {
        console.log('Doneeeee');
      },
      error: function(status, exception) {
        alert('Exception:', exception);
      }
    });
  });
  e.preventDefault();
});
```

Note: I've removed my .php extension using .htaccess so didn't added .php in action attribute

I don't know why it is not working, I've tried all the possible methods
Appreciate your help

Comment: It should be $("#formData").on('submit',function(e)....

Comment: Thankyou, now I'm not getting redirected by my from is not processing even thought I can see both my console logs

Comment: There's no need for the second `e.preventDefault()`. There's no default action for the `ready` event, AFAIK.

Comment: Modify your code such that you perform these actions on click of the save button. On successful validation, trigger the submit on form. That will do the rest

Comment: Don't use `contentType: false` and `processData: false` when you use `.serialize()`. You only need to use that if you're sending a `FormData` object.

Comment: @KK The way she's doing it is correct, using the `submit` event on the form.

Comment: @KK Why should she trigger the submit on the form if she wants to use AJAX instead?

Comment: `e.preventDefault()` should keep it redirecting. Something else must be causing that.